# Trusted Web Activity shows address bar after switching between different Apps

Tags: trusted-web-activity

I'm having a really weird behaviour with my TWA. When I am launching the app, the address bar is not shown and the app is running in standalone mode as expected.

But when I am switching between Apps (putting the app in the background), and coming back to it, something weird happens: the page reloads, and the address bar is shown at the top of my app. I am not really sure to understand what's happening here. Even more strange, it looks like this weird behaviour is not happening all the time.

Does anybody here encountered similar issues ?

I checked my assetlinks file, it's accessible and valid, app bundle and so on, everything looks fine. The fact that the app is not showing the bar at launch also seems to confirm that the problem is not coming from the certificate or a configuration issue. What else could cause the problem ?

**First launch (looking perfect):**

[image]

**Back from background:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have seen this occasionally as well.

Which version of **Chrome Custom Tabs** are you using? Seems like most articles/tutorials use **e446d08** which is quite outdated. Suggest trying a newer/latest version of it:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/commits/master

Their last commit comment suggests that they are still testing things:

> *There's definitely more we can test, but this is a start.*

https://chromium.googlesource.com/custom-tabs-client/+/da65829d7d4b80c00809c6c4aa7f61f88fc7ca26

Comment: I am using this one "d08e93fce3" found in the documentation for TWA provided by Google => https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/using-twa

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and my JS was causing it because of window.location.href

I fixed the problem by doing the below and following info from this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/origin

I was using the full address in the window.location.href

however when I changed it to use `window.location.origin` it worked

before:

```
window.location.href = "https://example.com/products";
```

after:

```
const result = window.location.origin;

window.location.href = result+"/products";
```

may be needed for security reasons.

Comment: needs formatting